# How to identify if file type is a json data or json schema

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

I want to know while uploading a file how to distinguish whether a user has uploaded the JSON schema file or actual JSON data file for that schema as both have .json type , unlike the XML or XSD case where from the file type we can identify if the user is uploading the XML or the XSD.

Comment: json schema should always contains "$schema" field

Comment: @FabrizioStellato - incorrect. JSON schema specification does not require the $schema property

Answer (score 3):

**Short Answer**

You can't.

**Long Answer**

Unlike XSD, a JSON schema can be expressed in terms which make it indistinguishable from a non-schema JSON document.

However, in practice, there may be things you can do. By convention, JSON schemas may begin with the *$schema* property telling a consumer what version of JSON schema is being used, eg:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {}
}
```

Additionally, JSON schemas may use the *$ref* property, which allows the schema author to reference other properties within the schema, eg:

```
"thing":{
    "$ref": "#/definitions/Thing"
}
```

There are a bunch of collection properties which may also give it away: `required[]`, `oneOf[]`, `allOf[]`. However, the main point is that it's possible to create a schema without using any of these elements.